# How do I use an inventory file for Ansible ad-hoc commands?

Tags: ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-ad-hoc

Ansible v2.2.1.0

I want to gather Ansible facts about a remote host defined in my `inv/remote_hosts` file, which looks like this:

```
[remote-host-0]
10.22.123.234

[remote-host-1]
10.22.234.123
```

How do I run the setup command and tell it to gather facts for remote-host-0?

```
$ ansible ??? -m setup ???
```

If I simply do this:

```
$ ansible remote-host-0 -m setup
```

I get:

> ERROR! Attempted to read "/path_to_my_ansible_dir/ansible//hosts" as YAML: Syntax Error while loading YAML.

It's looking for the wrong hosts file, and I get a YAML error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify an inventory file with the `-i` option:

```
ansible remote-host-0 -m setup -i inv/remote_hosts
```

Comment: so simple I missed it. Thanks!